# nginx error mapping

Tags: nginx

How can I map error codes/pages in nginx to my more descriptive file names?

e.g.,

I have a dir with errors like `404-NotFound` that I would like to easily map the 404 error code to in nginx. I do not want to have to specify each error_page mapping by hand as it would be tedious. It would also bloat the conf file because it would have to be done for each server.

I already have a map setup but new to nginx and can't figure out how to get it all to work together.

(All my error pages start with the error code so, in fact, I would rather have some way for the file to be automatically found since there is only one file per error code.

e.g., error 404 is mapped to file 404-NotFound.html and it would be nice if I didn't have to specify this but somehow it detected automatically.)

I would also like to support multiple languages...

Answer (score 3):

[error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) can contain variables in URI part but not in codes, so anyway it would require you to explicitly set that list. In decent Nginx versions (1.3.2, 1.2.2) [variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) `$status` appeared, allowing to approach your aim in a way like this:

```
error_page 404 403 … @err;

location @err {
    try_files /html/error/$status.html /html/error/default.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to test this, if you have the time to do it, try this:

```
  recursive_error_pages on;
  error_page 400 403 404 407 500 502 503 504 /path/to/$status-ErrorPage.html;
```

Good luck!

**Edit**: Did some research and found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/396654/status-code-in-nginx-try-files-directive), and now I [just learned](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html) it's a BAD idea